# Calcular o tempo de execução de um programa

Tags: python

Como faço para adicionar um "timer" no início do programa e ao decorrer da execução eu possa ler o tempo decorrido desde o inicio do programa em segundos?

Comment: Dê exemplos, por favor.

Comment: Tipo,ao iniciar o programa ele inicia uma contagem(em segundos),ao decorrer do programa eu peço para ler a quanto tempo o programa está sendo executado(Ex:80 Segundos) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta usar a biblioteca [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

```
import time

tempo_inicial = time.time()

funcao() # chame a função que deseja medir o tempo de execução aqui

print("--- %s segundos ---" % (time.time() - tempo_inicial))
```

saida:

```
--- 0.764891862869 segundos ---
```

Existe uma pergunta semelhante no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution)